# CakePHP 3 ACL management

Tags: permissions, acl, cakephp-3.x

I'm looking for something like the Alaxos ACL Plugin (https://github.com/oldskool/Acl) for CakePHP 3.x with all necessary views to manage acos, aros and acos_aros. Is that available? I have installed cakephp/acl and cakedc/users plugins and I read everywhere these two plugins are completely functional but I can't find any views to really manage the group and user permissions. Do I need to create them all by myself? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: check this https://www.ektanjali.com/products but its premium

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However I'd like to use something based on the official cakephp/acl plugin. Since the manual indicates this plugin is 'fully functional' I guess I'm only overlooking some built-in features to make everything work smoothly. Or am I wrong? In my previous version (2.x) I worked with the Alaxos ACL Plugin which did exactly what I needed. Now I already found https://github.com/mattmemmesheimer/cakephp-3-acl-example but I'm also missing the pages to set the permissions and also important the way to check the permission before showing a link. Can anyone advice me here?